# jquery Ajax responsetext "There was an error processing the request"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am getting this error ***"There was an error processing the request"*** in the UAT environment. In my local, the code seems to be working fine.

This line **Utility.WriteLogEvent("TestService", strMessage);** is writing directly to db. Either way if this line fails or not, I should still be able to recieve a message coming from the server since it is properly handled.

But since I don't receive any response from the server, that means my webmethod is not reachable.

Given that the code below works, is there anything that I need to set in the web.config to make this work? Or anywhere I can start inspecting on the IIS that could give me some clues?

Thanks.

```
$('#lnkTest').click(function () {
    alert('Click event is firing!');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/_layouts/ServiceForm.aspx/TestService",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d && response.d.length > 0) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert('responseText:' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my c# web method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string TestService()
{
    string strMessage = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        strMessage = "The service is running.";
        Utility.WriteLogEvent("TestService", strMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strMessage = "TestService fail.";

    }
    return strMessage;
}
```

Comment: Make Respective change in your url scheme? it might become problematic. Check in your exception on which particular location it is trying to access and it is not getting the webmethod location
? second problem might be that check calling of method in browser(use Firebug) and you will get better idea which exact location it is trying to access.

Comment: Url is fine. It's a sharepoint url, so I doubt it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. This is due to a dll deployed in the application server and it was blocked by the installed antivirus.

Answer (score 5):

For others who might come across the same error while calling a WebMethod with parameters.

Ensure that none of the arguments are empty as that also throws the same error without a proper reason. Provide a solution to prevent empty arguments from being passed to the Method on the client side. Perhaps an `if statement`.

Answer (score 0):

My web method was working correctly for small amount of data but I was receiving the same error message on calling the same web method with a parameter to return 500 rows (large amount of data):
`{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}`.

The reason for this error for me was that I had not set the `maxJsonLength` property in web.config of my server.
so I placed the following lines under the `configuration` section of web.config.

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

And my error was solved.

I ran the method locally after removing the above `maxJsonLength` property from my web.config file and received the following error.

```
{
    "Message": "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
}
```

So if you are having this error then set the `maxJsonLength` property in the web.config file as described above.